# How do I dump variables in Yii for debugging?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

How do I dump and print variables in Yii for debugging? I would like to use `var_dump()` or `print_r()`. I tried to use `Yii::trace()` but it crashes with this error in `runtime/logs/app.log`. It doesn't even tell me the line in my code that it fails.

```
2015-03-18 20:54:11 [::1][-][-][warning][yii\log\Dispatcher::dispatch] Unable to send log via yii\debug\LogTarget: Exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed'

in /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/AffiliateArbitrage/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-debug/LogTarget.php:58

Stack trace:
#0 /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/AffiliateArbitrage/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-debug/LogTarget.php(58): serialize(Array)
#1 /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/AffiliateArbitrage/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-debug/LogTarget.php(112): yii\debug\LogTarget->export(Array)
#2 /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/AffiliateArbitrage/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/log/Dispatcher.php(183): yii\debug\LogTarget->collect(Array, true)
#3 /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/AffiliateArbitrage/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/log/Logger.php(170): yii\log\Dispatcher->dispatch(Array, true)
#4 [internal function]: yii\log\Logger->flush(true)
#5 {main}
```

Reference
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-logging.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because you are asking about something like `var_dump` and `print_r`, I can advise built-in helper for this. It's called [yii\helpers\VarDumper](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-vardumper.html). [Yii::trace()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-baseyii.html#trace%28%29-detail) is for logging trace messages.

> **VarDumper is intended to replace the buggy PHP function `var_dump` and `print_r`**.
>
> It can correctly identify the recursively referenced objects in a
>   complex object structure. It also has a recursive depth control to
>   avoid indefinite recursive display of some peculiar variables.
>
> VarDumper can be used as follows,

```
VarDumper::dump($var);
```

Personally I don't use it, just tried only couple of times for testing.

I think is better to use [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) for that purposes.

See also [PsySH](http://psysh.org/).

Comment: Perfect! Old school debugging! Except that stupid default nav bar floating at the top that obscures the output...

Comment: Add `exit` or `die` right after dump the same as with regular `var_dump` and `print_r`.

Comment: Added link to another debugger that probably will help you more with this.

Comment: Psy SH looks really neat but there's probably something wrong with it. Composer didn't install any executable. Not only that, it's not clear how to connect the shell to the web server. It says it will drop into a shell if you add the debug line, but PHP is running in Apache in the background! How will it show a shell? There's no mention of setting a port or anything for remote debugging.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
<?php echo '<pre>'; print_r($model); exit; ?>
```

Comment: echo '<pre>'; print_r($model); exit; Tnks

Comment: <?php echo '<pre>';print_r($model);exit; ?>

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. If you realize you have forgotten something, or made a mistake, you should [edit] your answer, not leave it as a comment. Comments are not read by all, they could be deleted, and do not allow proper code formatting. Another user has already suggested an edit to fix it: please review it, edit your answer further if you think it's needed, and then remove the comments. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I used this, but I'm sure there's a better way.

```
Yii::warning('**********************', var_export($category,true));
```

`config/web.php`

```
    'log' => [
        ...
        'flushInterval' => 1, // for debug
        'targets' => [
            [
                ...
                'exportInterval' => 1, // for debug - slow
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Where can I see the message?

Comment: Actually I wanted to see messages almost immediately in log files for Yii commands. This helped me, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Use this, to see your variable or object array.

`use yii\helpers\VarDumper;`

`VarDumper::dump($variableArray ,  $dept = 10,  $highlight = true);`

To detail you can read the doc
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basevardumper.html#dump()-detail

Answer (score 1):

You can do it yourself:
In your main index page (`back/index.php` or `front/index.php`) add this code to the top `ob_start();`. Then define 2 functions for better debugging

```
function dd($v){
    ob_clean(); 
    var_dump($v);
    exit;
}
function dj($v){
    ob_clean(); 
    echo CJSON::encode($v);
    exit;
}
```

and add `ob_end_flush();` at the very end of your main index page . Now you can call `dd($model)` or `dj($model)`. There you had your dumper working. Congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

You should install tracy\tracy.

```
dump($var);
bdump($var); // dump in bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `dd` existed *by default* in my basic Yii2 application.

See [`Yii wiki`](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/793/debuging-variables-in-yii2) and the output looks just like Laravel! Obviously, it does use `VarDumper::dump($yourVar);` under the hood.

```
<?php

$yourVar = 90; // or whatever

dd($yourVar);
```

Answer (score -1):

I had written an article about this problem with debug variables in Yii 2:

> Since for the sake of Simplicity and Quick Development, I’ve created a helper for those who use Yii. You can just call `dd($var1, $var2, ….);` for dump & die or `d($var1, $var2, ….);` for dump data.

Details and installation instructions are on: https://dangnhsite.wordpress.com/2016/04/06/variable-debug-in-yii-2/